# How to run functions over elements inside flux in parallel?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am new to Project Reactor. Is it possible to run functions over elements inside flux in parallel?

For example, I have a `Flux<Dog>` and methods `setAge` and `setName` that do some calculation and set that data to age and name fields inside Dog. The methods are independent, and I want them to execute in same time.

```
Flux.fromIterable(mapToResult())
    .parallel(10)
    .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
    .flatMap(result -> Mono.zip(setAge(result)
            .onErrorResume(err -> {
                err.printStackTrace();
                return Mono.justOrEmpty(result);
            }), setName(result).onErrorComplete()
            .onErrorResume(err -> {
                err.printStackTrace();
                return Mono.justOrEmpty(result);
            })).map(Tuple2::getT2)
    ).subscribe();
```

I have tried the above, but the following executes the setAge first and then setName. Is it possible for setName not to wait on setAge?

Note: inside setAge I have Thread.sleep() with high value.

setAge method

```
private static Mono<Dog> setAge(Dog dog) {
    return Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
        log.info("Setting age "+dog);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        dog.age = 10;
        return dog;
    });
}
```

With completable futures I will need something like this to achieve what I want:

```
.thenCompose(result -> setAge(result).thenCombine(setName(result), (r1,r2) -> result).
```

Comment: Can you show us your setAge implementation? I'm suspecting you placed the Thread.sleep() outside the Mono, and thus it will sleep during the Flux pipeline assembly, and not the pipeline execution.

Comment: @PatrickHooijer edited. The thread is inside, but regardless even if there isn't sleep the first logs are always from the Setting age instead of Setting age and Setting name in parallel, like when I use CompletableFutures.

Comment: ParallelFlux use "rails" to maximize parallelism. But it also means that a task affected to a rail is likely to remain on that thread. In your case, the "rails" distribute the entire zip operator to threads. It means that each `result` object will be sent to a single thread where the zip operations will be launched... sequentially. In your case, I think you should rely on Reactor basic concurrency model. ParallelFlux are a very specific beast that should be used very carefully. Try the same code by removing `.parallel()`, and replace `runOn(...)` with `subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure that it is safe to mutate the result object directly. I think that it is required to create a new pojo instance with updated age/name, to guarantee concurrent state management.

Comment: @amanin thanks for the suggestion, the issue was that I should use .delaySubscription or the other delay functions, instead of thread.sleep() as it is blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thread.sleep should not be used, but some of the delay methods provided from project-reactor. Example delayElement, delaySubscription etc.